# How to add advanced search to sharepoint online library

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, search, content-search-web-part, advanced-search

can anyone teach me how to add advanced search function to SharePoint Online? This is what i have now.

[image]

This is what I want, with the options like **MATCH CASE** and **FIND WHOLE WORD ONLY** appear in Word Online

[image]